# Can not get FileInfo back from configuration

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="loggingConfigs">


    <section name="LoggingParameters"
          type="Framework.Logging.LoggingParameters, Framework.Logging" />

  </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

  <loggingConfigs>

    <LoggingParameters

        myconfig="C:mydir\mypath1\mypath2\log4net.config" 

      />


  </loggingConfigs>
</configuration>   




public class LoggingParameters : ConfigurationSection
{

    [ConfigurationProperty("myconfig", IsRequired = true)]
    private string ConfigFileLoc
    {
        get { return (string)this["myconfig"]; }
    }


    public FileInfo MyConfigFile
    {
        get
        {
            string s = ConfigFileLoc;  <--- getting empty string here..don't know why
            return new FileInfo(s);
        }

    }
}
```

When I make the following call else where in my application,

```
FileInfo f = new Framework.Logging.LoggingParameters().MyConfigFile;
```

**the ConfigFileLoc always comes back as blank.** I can not figure out why its blank.. **why the string is empty**.. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the SectionGroup (don't know if that is a requirement for you)

```
  <configSections>    
      <section name="LoggingParameters"
            type="Framework.Logging.LoggingParameters, Framework.Logging" />      
  </configSections>
  <LoggingParameters myconfig="C:mydir\mypath1\mypath2\log4net.config" />
```

And got the FileInfo with this code (path is not empty anymore)

```
LoggingParameters config = (LoggingParameters)ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("LoggingParameters");
FileInfo fInfo = config.MyConfigFile;
```

[This post by Scott Mitchell](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133931/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx) may help you

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid writing configuration access code by hand. It's too easy to foobar. Check out this addin that lets you visually design your configurations. Let it write the boilerplate code for  you while you focus solely on the visual designer and your problem domain.

http://csd.codeplex.com/